# Hide button after ng-click using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and wanted to know how to hide a button after clicking (using ng-click) on it.

```
<button ng-click="xyz()" class="btn-default pull-right">
    Start
</button>
```

Comment: <button ng-click="xyz()" class="btn-default pull-right">Start</button>

Comment: You want to hide own button or another one

Comment: I want to hide the same Start button

Comment: Hide or disable?

Comment: It shouldn't be visible, hence prefer to hide it

Comment: is below code is working?

Comment: It isn't working yet

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you needs two things:

- A variable leveraging the button visibility
- A function to update this variable (you could do it in the HTML but I discourage it).

So you would have your button:

```
<button ng-click="hideButton()" ng-show="isButtonVisible === true" class="btn-default pull-right">
    Start
</button>
```

Then, you would have the following variables

```
$scope.isButtonVisible = true; // true to make the button visible by default
```

And finally, the function that toggles it:

```
$scope.hideButton = function() {
    $scope.isButtonVisible = false;
}
```

Note that you could use `ng-if` to remove the button from the DOM if you won't need it again.

Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/fnW8HR58zKHs4T34XRan

Note that this is pretty much the most basic question you could have on AngularJS, so I would advice you to read a bit about it before asking Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable to denote the visibility of the button, its value will change with click event.

```
<button ng-click="clickEventFunction(params)" ng-hide="isButtonVissible">Button</button>
```

The default value of this variable should be "false" to show the button

```
$scope.isButtonVissible = false
```

Then in the clickEventFunction, change the value to hide the button

```
$scope.clickEventFunction = function(params){
$scope.isButtonVissible = true; 
//* Do the logic code
}
```

Comment: `isButtonVissible` is a very confusing name for a variable that hides a button when it is `true`.

Comment: Not a technical issue, but the spelling should be visible, not vissible

Answer (score -1):

In View:

```
 <button ng-click="hideBtn = true" ng-hide="hideBtn">Button</button>
```

In controller :

```
 $scope.hideBtn = false;
```

Comment: `isButtonVissible` is a very confusing name for a variable that hides a button when it is `true`.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to the question with some assistance. Created an event in the click function and was able to hide the button.

```
<button ng-click="xyz($event)" class="btn-default pull-right">Start</button>

$scope.xyz = function ($event) {
    $($event.target).hide();
```

Cheers to all your guidance.

Comment: That's pretty much the worse you could come up with. This is totally against angular principles. Here, you're using jQuery to hide an element where you should do it with Angular. Read my answer to see the correct way on doing this.

Comment: Okay I will check on that as suggested by you.